# Different ways to assess the quality of questions (also: how to find good and bad questions)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

EDIT initially posted question had queries that might have returned wrong results, this is hopefully corrected now /EDIT

This is not really a feature request, but more of an analysis of current state in respect to quality of question on EL&U. To formally turn it into a question, I pose the following:

> Is there a metric that is more adequate to judge the quality of questions than the raw score and if yes, what is it?

(but only from data on the actual site; external reviews, references and opinions are good, but out of the scope of this question).

I feel that judging the quality from top score questions is not enough and can lead to wrong conclusions on the health of the community.

Here I will propose a few other views

- top favorite questions - [results](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/s/567/most-favorited-questions)
- top questions according to views/score ratio - [results](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/q/106435/lowest-views-score-ratio-top-score-views-ratio)
- top views questions - [results](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/q/106436/top-views-questions)

Accidentally, the second query that looks at the ratio, if sorted in reverse and will show some of the 'disappointing' questions - the ones that a lot of people will read and a lot of people will *not* vote up. [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/q/106443/low-quality-according-to-view-vote-ratio) are the results for that one (the queries have different cut offs for score) - you will find some of the recently discussed low quality questions here.

If you have other interesting queries feel free to add them to the question or in the answer.